# Grouping and counting Item in my database

Tags: django, database, django-models

I am creating an app that keeps track of stock data. How can I write a query to group any items stored in a column? (ie the name column). Also, I would like to count the grouped items. Any help would be appreciated.

```
   class Stock (models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
        quantity = models.IntegerField(defualt=0)
        price = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: Instead of storing `name` as a `CharField` this should ideally be a foreign key to some model (e.g. perhaps named `Product`).